# Message display in alert window

Tags: java, struts

I'm studying the Struts model and I'm just wondering how to show result message through an alert window.

Result message returned by this code:

```
<html:messages id="msg" header="message.header" footer="message.footer">
    <li><b><bean:write name="msg" /></b></li>
</html:messages>
```

Comment: Do you mean in a JavaScript alert popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround. "bean:write" tag you can replace by Expression Language.

```
<script>var txt = '';</script>

<html:messages id="msg">
    <script>txt += '${msg}\n';</script>
</html:messages>

<script>alert(txt);</script>
```

Comment: Thanks~ ^^. i try then just show ${msg} message in alert window. but, i get your hint. thanks~

Comment: of course you can write `<script>txt += '<bean:write name="msg" />\n';</script>`